# Java How 'refresh' jars in a war file

Tags: java

I'm debugging a project, but when a create a warfile the jars inside don't seems to be up to date, (i made those jars).
I realized about this issue when i was testing the war file on the server, i modified one of the jars to send a message when the server receives a petition.

This message is never sent. 
There is a command like the `'mvn clean package'` to re-build all the project?.
I create the war file like this `jar cvf web-archive.war`.

Comment: if you have a target folder, try deleting the contents and build again

Comment: It looks like you are not declaring the JARs as dependencies with a correct updated version number. Cleaning won't force Maven to re-download the JARs unless you force it. If you want to work on both projects at the same time, you can open them both and the Maven plugin in Eclipse is smart enough to use the compiled files directly.

Comment: Include a minimal Pom declaration and fire structure that demonstrates your problem please.

Answer (score 2):

As per other comments, most likely your libraries jars are not updated. You need to rebuild them before creating war file.  if you already using maven for libraries why not to use

> There is a command like the 'mvn clean package' to re-build all the
>   project?

Yes, there is such a command and it will rebuild the **project**. But keep in mind, that it will not rebuild projects the current project is dependent on (i.e your libraries). You need to run this command for all 'libraries' projects.

I will suggest to use `mvn clean install` instead as it will rebuild your project and put the jar into your local maven repository so all other projects can use your locally build jar.

As you already using maven why not use it to build your war files as well. This is super convenient. Have a look at [Maven WAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

A possible cause: you've updated your jar file without changing the version number causing maven to assume it can use an outdated cached copy. Occasionally I've had to:

- delete my target folder
- remove the artifact(s) from my local .m2/ cache
- mvn clean install the dependencies
- mvn clean package my project

Comment: This steps are overkill. Changing the version number is not required, you just need to build and install your project. In this case, maven will put the latest version of your plugin into a local maven repository.  So `mvn clean install` should be enough.

Comment: Agreed, but on one occasion I had to resort to this as maven stubbornly refused to cooperate. Think it was that for some reason the updated jar was building but not getting installed as expected.